# How to select the middle 3 digits in a query. I am using yii2

Tags: jquery, mysql, database, yii2

For example, I have a field called account_code (int).

account_name: **Sample Account**
account_code: **1-100-200-001**

How can I get the the '200' value in a mysql query? I'm using Yii2.

Comment: is the format of the number always the same? you can use split like `account_code.split("-")[2]` where account_code is the number

Comment: yes that format is uniform. what happens when i split it? sorry i am a bit of a newbie in yii2.

Comment: This is going to take a big ugly MySQL query.  If you can at all split the code in JavaScript then you should probably do that.  See my deleted answer below for the MySQL carnage.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i doubt user can see the deleted answer. Il copy paste it here. tim's answer `SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(account_code, INSTR(account_code, '-') + 1), '.', 1)
FROM yourTable`

Comment: @guradio My answer was wrong...it would be so ugly that I gave up halfway.  Use JavaScript.  Save the universe.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with Yii2 you can generate models and CRUD functionality using [gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html). Once you have your account model defined you can load a specific item from your table like so:

```
$account_name = "Big Account"; //the name of the account whose code I want to parse
$account_model = Account::findOne(['account_name'=> $account_name]);
```

Now you can use php to parse the code as a string:

```
$code = $account_model->$account_code
$first_separator = stripos($code,"-");
$second_separator = stripos($code,"-",$first_separator+1);
$third_separator = stripos($code,"-",$second_separator+1);
$middle_code_length = $third_separator - $second_separator;
$middle_value = substr($code,$second_separator+1,$middle_code_length);
```

This should get you what you want. Try it out and let me know. similarly if for some specific reason you wan to use javascript check of the docs on string manipulations [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_methods.asp) and follow the idea above.